# EnvStats simulateVector function

Tags: r, envstats

I'm using the **EnvStats** package more specifically the *simulateVector* function to generate random samples from pdf's.

I've tried using a Normal pdf and varying the parameters that truncate this pdf:

```
> vfy <- simulateVector(10, distribution = "norm",
+                param.list = list(mean = 400, sd = 40), seed = 47,
+                sort = FALSE, left.tail.cutoff = 1, right.tail.cutoff = 1)
> vfy
 [1] 479.7879 428.4457 407.4162 388.7294 404.3510 356.5705 360.5807 400.6052 389.9182 341.3700
> vfy <- simulateVector(10, distribution = "norm",
+                param.list = list(mean = 400, sd = 40), seed = 47,
+                sort = FALSE, left.tail.cutoff = 0, right.tail.cutoff = 0)
> vfy
 [1] 479.7879 428.4457 407.4162 388.7294 404.3510 356.5705 360.5807 400.6052 389.9182 341.3700
```

For my surprise the results do not vary.... What's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `left.tail.cutoff` and `right.tail.cutoff` arguments are only relevant when you use `sample.method = "LHS"` for Latin Hypercube sampling.

The default is `sample.method = "SRS"` for simple random sampling, which uses the `rnomr()` function. The help file states "This argument is ignored if `sample.method="SRS"`."

See `?simulateVector()` for the default arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I thought LHS was the default sampling method. By the way do you know how can one specify lower and upper limit values instead of percentages? Thanks

Comment: No, sorry. I don't think you can specify lower and upper limit values directly. You might have to calculate the expected probability of the values based on the distribution you're using.